# Powering and keeping 5050 leds in sync

Tags: electrical, led

I want to set up two strips of led lights in a room with each having their own power supply. However, the problem arises of keeping them in sync in lighting modes other than static.

Info: 5050 RGB, 4 wires, one 12V 10A power supply, one 12V 6A power supply, already have controller and an amplifier.

Would connecting the strips as shown below work, and will they stay in sync?

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Are you trying to Sync the rotation of the colors so they will be both the same at the same time, but controlled by two different controllers?   Probably you can get it close, but it probably will never be exact, unless the 2 controllers can talk to each other.

Comment: That's my goal, but I thought connecting them syncs them regardless of multiple controllers. Or is that not how it works?

Comment: your diagram shows at least 3 strips .... one connected to the bottom power supply and two connected to the top power supply .... when drawing a diagram like yours, it is not necessary to draw the outline of the room .... something like `[power]-------leds-----`  drawn twice with a line showing the actual interconnection ..... then describe the connection between the two using a wiring diagram or a picture ..... also add a link to where you purchased these

Comment: Updated answer based on new info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so, you'll need exactly one controller, and one or more amplifiers depending on how fancy you want to get.  You don't show any of that on your drawing.

The Controller takes 12VDC power and outputs R,G,B and Common. This can be both the signal driving any number of amplifiers, or the power driving a limited number of LED strips.

The important component is the *amplifier*.   It *inputs* two things: a **power input** of 12V in large amounts; and a **signal input** consisting of R,G,B and C (common) from a controller.  The signal input is simply the RGBC output of the controller.  The amplifier *outputs* **LED drive output** consisting of R, G, B and C (common).  This can feed one or several LED strings, limited by the rating of the power supply and the amplifier.

### The minimum configuration

Install the controller *just past* the power supply on the lower right.  The controller will directly drive the bottom-edge LED string.

At the place you mark "connector", the botton LED strip will be totally severed from the other LED strips.  However, a 4-wire (RGBC) cable will continue onward from the end of this LED strip, and it will go to the amplifier.  These can be very small wires, they carry virtually no current.

The top center power supply will be replaced by a power supply *and an amplifier*.  The power supply output goes to the amplifier power input.  The signal input comes from the 4-wire cable from the bottom-edge strip.  The amplifier's RGBC output will then drive both LED strips along the top, left and right.

Comment: My fault, I should have provided more information, they are RGB strips and I already bought a controller. I will most likely buy an amplifier and place it where the connector is in the diagram. The other power supply is rated to power two strips by using a splitter.

Comment: @EVking Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: do they have 4 wires or just 3? if 3, then you can provide power in the middle as suggested, so long as you run the signal line in series. If 4 wires, then you need to dupe the levels, not just add more power, which is more complex.